# Apache stripping comments from html

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, html

I have a deployment where Apache forwards to Tomcat running on the same system.
I'm running into a situation where Apache is stripping out comments in html returned by Tomcat. This is causing lines like the following to be removed causing the js to fail on IE:

```
"<!--if IE><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/excanvas.js"></script><!endif>"
```

I have mod_rewrite, mod_proxyhtml and of course proxy_ajp. I tried adding "ProxyHTMLStripComments Off" but that doesn't seem to help.

What am I missing ?

Comment: You seem to be missing 'the following', there.

Comment: I don't know tomcat, but just an idea. Couldn't it be some module for minification? the comments are the first thing stripped by those

Comment: I know the problem is not with tomcat as if I access tomcat directly, the line is sent back. I tried turning off mod-deflate based on your comment, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I know that your question is ancient, but for the people who are struggling with this issue i have the following solution:

Apache proxy html rewrites html following the guidelines specified by the html standard you are using. If you are using your proxy for a modern site i suggest you specify the Doctype by adding `ProxyHTMLDocType "<!DOCTYPE html>"`

This will ensure that your html is rewritten accordingly.